# How to scale/resize a view and its content proportionally?

Tags: java, android

sorry if the title isn't good. I'd like to scale/resize a view and its following child.

I tried using `setScaleX` and `setScaleY`, which is the easiest one, but the view bounds remain unchanged and leaves a blank margin. I tried to resize it manually by changing the height and width, including it childs, but it's kinda difficult for me to maintain the proportional size of the childs if it contains TextView.

Is there a best way to achive it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method to scale a view and its following childs. Hope it can help you

```
        public static void scaleView(View view, float scaleX, float scaleY) {
            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                int viewCount = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < viewCount; i++) {
                    scaleView(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i), scaleX, scaleY);
                }
            }
            view.setScaleX(scaleX);
            view.setScaleY(scaleY);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to calculate proportional height and width of each layout and its child .And then you can calculate margins and set `MarginLayoutParms` to each view.

And proportional height and width  should be calculated with respect to their parent layout height and width each time you change height and width of view , dynamically proportion calculate and height and width and margins are set accordingly.